# Failed to launch app on emulator: Failed to install apk to emulator:

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-emulator, ionic-framework

I had moved my android sdk from my home directory to another drive. And when I try to emulate my ionic app using android emulator I get the following error:

> Failed to launch app on emulator: Failed to install apk to emulator:
>   pkg: /data/local/tmp/MainActivity-debug.apk Failure
>   [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK] rm failed for -f, Read-only file system

Does any one have a clue what might be wrong here ??

Answer (score 0):

When deploying your app to your device (which is emulator for you), the deploy procedure is:

```
1. Sync the fundamental libraries,
2. Remove previous app package,
3. Install the new package.
```

It seems like it's failed to remove the previous package since the file system is read-only, consider check if the image file is read-only.